# Tracing a PID using multiple dtrace scripts

Tags: solaris, dtrace

I am trying to run multiple dtrace scripts at the same time which does on-cpu and off-cpu stack traces of the same pid.

After I run one of the script, the second one throws an error saying that pid is already being traced.

Is there any way to run multiple scripts tracing the same pid? I can't combine the scripts because I want the output to be in different files.

Comment: Why not just tag your outputs with different values and separate them later with something like `grep` or `awk`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle how would I tag different output to grep it?

Comment: How do you create the output now?  All you need to do is add a distinctive value to different outputs.

Comment: I pass an output file to dtrace itself which creates the output. So, if I run different probes together, they will output to the same file which I won't be able to differentiate.